# Pra que serve o sealed em C#?

Tags: c#, classes, característica-linguagem

Vi uma classe em C# que estava declarada assim, numa resposta que li no SOen:

```
public sealed class Link
{
     // Resto do código
}
```

Para que serve a palavra chave `sealed` no caso acima?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Bem, em resumo o `sealed` é para indicar que a classe não poderá ser herdada por outras. É o mesmo que o `final` do Java.

Muitos dizem que deveria ser o padrão, já que herança quase nunca é a solução. Herança traz uma bagagem muito forte e um fardo para a manutenção já que qualquer alteração nesta classe potencialmente afetará o funcionamento de todas as derivadas.

Uma estrutura de dados como uma classe é útil, mas a herança nem tanto. Claro, tem seus usos. Organizar tudo junto no objeto é muito mais vantajoso e ajuda muito mais que permitir o reuso direto. Na maioria dos casos que a pessoa quer fazer uma herança deveria fazer uma composição.

Uma `struct` é implicitamente `sealed`, e deveriam ter padronizado isso na classe. Deveria ter uma palavra opcional como `open`, `inheritable`, ou até um `virtual` pra usar algo já existente, ou algo semelhante a isso, o que importa é a ideia. A diferença fundamental de uma classe é que ela é sempre por referência, e, salvo otimização, tem o local de armazenamento no *heap* (alguns hoje admitem que poderia ser melhor nem isso ser padrão e o programador ter que dizer onde vai, mas é uma corrente pequena para o C#).

Classes seladas são simples e confiáveis, precisam de menos testes e podem evoluir melhor. Claro, se forem bem feitas. Classes abertas para herança são problemáticas até quando tudo é feito direito. Fica pior quando quando a classe pode ser herdada **e** instanciada. Há quem considere que classes abertas à herança sempre deveriam ser abstratas, o que eu concordo cada vez mais. Muitos problemas de OOP não existiriam assim. Mas admito também que tem caso que pode ser útil ter ambos, feito com muito cuidado.

Então use `sealed` por padrão até que tenha certeza que precisa da herança. E aí desenhe a classe para a herança, o que é absurdamente mais difícil.

No C# a ideia da herança padrão foi copiada do Java e foi uma ideia ruim. Já existia antes, mas fazia mais sentido em outras linguagens. Java, pela sua filosofia, errou e C# foi na onda.

## Em métodos

Esse atributo também é usado em métodos, de forma bem mais rara. Nesse caso você está proibindo um método ser sobreposto quando originalmente ele era virtual, e portando polimórfico. Só faz sentido usá-lo em métodos que são herdados virtualmente e que deseja impedir que ele continue virtual a partir dali. Então ele só faz sentido existir em uma classe já herdada e em um método que na ascendente foi marcado como `virtual`. Métodos não explicitamente `virtual` podem ser considerados `sealed` implicitamente.

Novamente considero um erro. Se pretende que continue sendo virtual deveria ter que dizer isso. Embora nesse caso tem lá suas desvantagens. Prefiro o implícito por coerência, mas ser explícito tem seu mérito.

O nome é esquisito, mas era o que tinha. Ele seria um `nonvirtual`.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Apenas por curiosidade, o `VB.NET` usa o nome `NotInheritable` que eu acho mais didático. A ideia de herança por padrão eu acho que tem mais a ver com outras linguagens OO e não com o Java. Embora exista [uma citação do criador do C#](https://www.codebrary.com/2018/03/deep-inside-c-sharp-interview-with.html) que afirma que o C# não copiou o Java, me parece que a ideia do `sealed` tem as mesmas razões de otimização do compilador.

Comment: @Pagotti Sequer gosto muito do termo linguagem OO, porque na prática isso é algo bem secundário nelas. Mas tudo bem usar. De fato, mas estamos falando de que linguagem então? Eu adoro essa ideia de não cópia do Java, embora seja um pouco tb, e eu dei palestra esses dias sobre isto, gosto da ideia de ter copiado mais até o C++, mas no fundo boa parte foi copiada do Java sim, inclusive esse erro. C++ sequer tinha a ideia que a herança não ser possível. Se fosse uma cópia aperfeiçoada do C++ `sealed` seria padrão. Como não é é cópia do erro cometido em Java. Não entendi a otimização do compilador

Comment: A parte da otimização é por causa de uma frase no documento de especificação da linguagem C#: "The sealed modifier is primarily used to prevent unintended derivation, but it also enables certain run-time optimizations. In particular, because a sealed class is known to never have any derived classes, it is possible to transform virtual function member invocations on sealed class instances into non-virtual invocations"

Comment: Tem discussão no SO sobre isso (pesquisei agora) e há controvérsias. Deve ser coisa das primeiras versões da linguagem. Talvez isso não se aplique mais nas versões atuais.

Comment: na verdade o texto não é muito bom, porque o fato da classe ser `sealed` não quer dizer muito a não ser que nenhum método pode ser virtual, mas a otimização ocorrerá de qq forma se o método não for virtual, em qualquer tipo de classe. Mostre a discussão.

Comment: O texto é do manual da própria Microsoft. Uma das discussões está aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2134/1700943

Comment: @Pagotti e o texto é ruim. A resposta aceita na discussão é ruim ,tanto que não tem tantos votos, uma coisa boa do SOen é que mesmo que lá também tenha dos "maria vai com as outras" que votam na aceita, tem muito + q votam em outras coisas. O artigo do Patrick Smacchia é bom, mas redundante, porque há o ponto de facilitar a manutenção que eu disse, e há o da performance que não é por é ser selada e sim por não haver virtual, o fato de ser selada é colateral e contextual e o terceiro ponto tem a ver com o primeiro, é manutenção.

Comment: Tem um tarados por OOP ideologistas que acham que classe aberta é bom, em geral os pragmáticos tem mais voz e falam o que eu falei. Claramente o cara da resposta aceita entende os efeitos, mas não o porquê, aí fala umas coisas que parecem certas, mas não são na essência. A resposta mais votada é melhor. Quase sempre os votos dizem mais que a aceitação. Acho até que a classificação das respostas não deveria considerar a aceita. tem outras lá com poucos votos que se perdem por não ser a aceita (a maioria das pessoas não olha as que não foram aceitas ou pelo menos tiveram muitos votos).

Comment: Inclusive tem uma com atualização que é ótima e tem poucos votos, ainda que o cara não tenha entendido a colateralidade da questão. E C# 8 deve ajudar ainda mais com *non-null referece types*. E como sempre o que tem de melhor ali é o comentário do Jon Skeet mais embaixo.

Answer (score 6):

É um modificador que, em classes, define que outras classes não possam herdar da especificada.

```
public class A { }
public sealed class B : A { } // Funciona normal. B herda de A e não pode ser herdada.
public class C : B { }        // Erro de compilação.
```

Este modificador também pode ser usado em membros de classes que possam ser herdadas. Isso faz com que a classe filha possa usar o comportamento definido na classe pai, mas que não possa alterá-lo.

```
class A
{
    protected virtual void Metodo1() => Console.WriteLine("Classe A -> 1");
    protected virtual void Metodo2() => Console.WriteLine("Classe A -> 2");
}

class B : A
{
    protected sealed override void Metodo1() => Console.WriteLine("Classe B -> 1");
    protected override void Metodo2() => Console.WriteLine("Classe B -> 2");
}

class C : B
{         
    protected override void Metodo1() => Console.WriteLine("Classe C -> 1");     
    // (^) Erro de compilação.
    protected override void Metodo2() => Console.WriteLine("Classe C -> 2");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

No caso de classes, o modificador `sealed` serve para indicar que ela não pode ser herdada.

```
class A {}      
sealed class B : A {}
```

Ou seja, B pode herdar de A, mas se eu criar uma classe C e tentar herdar de B, causará um erro de compilação.

```
// Causa erro
class C : B {}
```

A mesma coisa acontece com overriding de métodos. Se você tentar sobreescrever um método com o modificador `sealed`, também causará um erro de compilação.

No seu exemplo, o modificador indica que nenhuma outra classe poderá herdar da classe `Link`

Comment: Banaca, pelo visto lembra um pouco o `final` do PHP/Java.

Answer (score 4):

`sealed`, quando usado em uma declaração de classe, impede que outras classes herdem dela.

```
public class TesteA { //... }
```

```
public sealed class TesteB : TesteA { //... }
```

Neste caso acima, `TesteB` herda de `TesteA`, mas uma tentativa de herdar de `TesteB` causará um erro de compilação.

A palavra chave `sealed` também pode ser usada em métodos ou propriedades:

```
public class TesteA { 
    protected virtual void Hello() { Console.WriteLine("TesteA cumprimenta você!"); }
}
```

```
public class TesteB : TesteA { 
    sealed protected override void Hello() { Console.WriteLine("TesteB cumprimenta você!"); }
}
```

Aqui vai disparar erro de compilação CS0239, não é possível sobreescrever um membro declarado como `sealed`

```
public class TesteC : TesteB { 
    protected override void Hello() { Console.WriteLine("TesteC cumprimenta você!"); }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

É um modificador que impede que outras classes herdam dessa classe. Esse modificador pode também ser utilizado em propriedades ou métodos.

Um exemplo básico que exemplifique isso:

```
class B {}
sealed class A: B {}
```

essa herança funciona onde `A` herda de `B`, mas, se for ao contrário isso não funciona pela restrição do modificador.

<sup>***Referencia:*** [sealed (Referência de C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/sealed)</sup>